# Different results returned when ignoring Primary Key index. Daylight Savings Time related bug?

Tags: mysql

I'm hoping you can help explain this behavior or try to reproduce the issue so I can be confident filing a bug report.

Essentially, I get different results from these queries:

```
# returns 0
select count(*) as COUNT_WITH_INDEX
from a
where id = 1  and begin_time='2018-11-04 01:01:00.000';

# returns 1
select count(*) as COUNT_WITHOUT_INDEX
from a ignore index (PRIMARY)
where id = 1  and begin_time='2018-11-04 01:01:00.000';
```

The key difference is the use of `ignore index (PRIMARY)`.

In case the date didn't stick out to you immediately, that date falls in the "Fall Behind" hour of Daylight Savings transition for 'US/Central' timezone.  1:01am occurred twice on 2018-11-04.  I only found issues with timestamps that fall in this window, so I suspect its a bug with how DST rules are applied.

Regardless of whether or not I need to use `convert_tz()` to correctly get the date I want, there's still the fact that I get different results with and without the `PRIMARY` key index.

Full test case:

```
create database if not exists test_dt;
use test_dt;

drop table if exists a;

CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `begin_time` timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`begin_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


set TIME_ZONE='+0:00';

insert into a values(1, '2018-11-04 06:01:00.000');
insert into a values(1, '2018-11-04 07:01:00.000');

set TIME_ZONE='US/Eastern';

select * from a;

# returns 0
select count(*) as COUNT_WITH_INDEX
from a
where id = 1  and begin_time='2018-11-04 01:01:00.000';

# returns 1
select count(*) as COUNT_WITHOUT_INDEX
from a ignore index (PRIMARY)
where id = 1  and begin_time='2018-11-04 01:01:00.000';

set TIME_ZONE='US/Central';
# repeat w/ Central if you like
```

Side note: [Install Time Zone data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation) to use named time zones.

Tested on:: CentOS 7 w/ 5.6.36 and 5.6.43.  I don't have 5.7 or 8.0 installations handy.

Another side note:  The initial problem I encountered was that joins between parent-child tables were not returning data with composite PK (id, timestamp).  Since timestamps are stored in UTC format, I wouldn't think DST dates would be an issue, but here I am.

Do you have an explanation for the behavior?
Do you think it's a bug?

Thanks!

**Edit**
Additional info per comments

> What result do you get if you drop the p.k?

```
set TIME_ZONE='+0:00';

insert into a values(1, '2018-11-04 06:01:00.000');
insert into a values(1, '2018-11-04 07:01:00.000');


select * from a ;   

select 'Set time_zone=US/Central' as msg;
set TIME_ZONE='US/Central';
+------------------+
| COUNT_WITH_INDEX |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

drop index `primary` on a;

select count(*) as COUNT_DROPPED_PK
from a
where id = 1  and begin_time='2018-11-04 01:01:00.000';


+------------------+
| COUNT_DROPPED_PK |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

set TIME_ZONE='+0:00';

select * from a;

+----+-------------------------+
| id | begin_time              |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2018-11-04 06:01:00.000 |
|  1 | 2018-11-04 06:01:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

**Notice** If I change the TZ to US/Central, drop the PK, then set the TZ back to '+0:00', I can see that the data is screwed up.  Both records are `06:01` time, when one was inserted `07:01`.  That behavior is not logical to me since the timestamps should always be UTC in the backend.

> 1) Show the output of set TIME_ZONE='US/Eastern'; select * from a; 2) What if set TIME_ZONE='-4:00';?

```
set TIME_ZONE='US/Eastern';
select * from a;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | begin_time              |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2018-11-04 01:01:00.000 |
|  1 | 2018-11-04 02:01:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+

set TIME_ZONE='-4:00';
select * from a;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | begin_time              |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | 2018-11-04 02:01:00.000 |
|  1 | 2018-11-04 03:01:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+
```

Comment: What result do you get if you drop the p.k?

Comment: 1) Show the output of `set TIME_ZONE='US/Eastern'; select * from a;` 2) What if `set TIME_ZONE='-4:00';`?

Comment: @Lennart Similar behavior to ignoring the index.  See above.  Changing the TZ to US/Central, dropping the PK actually corrupts data, as the timestamp '2018-11-04 07:01:00.000' is changed to '2018-11-04 06:01:00.000'. :(

Comment: @Akina Output added above.  Problems don't seem to occur with the fixed offset timezones, just DST time zones.

Comment: `-4:00` does not have DST; `US/Eastern` does.

Comment: @RickJames Agreed.  My issue is with DST timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer that I don't like :

> Indexed searches convert the "value or range to be matched " into a
>   UTC time to be compared against the indexed value.
>
> Non-indexed searches convert the "stored value" from UTC to the session time zone
>   for comparison.

That explains why I get different results with and without an index.  To me it feels like the implementation is broken, but I don't know what I would do for an easy fix. /shrug

Fortunately we can work around the issue in this case, but we are reconsidering how to handle this in the future.